# Get list of all declared exchanges on a RabbitMQ server with C#

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm implementing a RabbitMQ adapter.
The idea is to show in another system a list of already declared exchanges. 
So i have a C# adapter class, within it i want to implement the logic that will retrieve all exchanges declared on a server and then pass it to a third-system to display them to the user. Is there any existing way to do that?

I've checked for methods on ConnectionFactory and IModel instances but couldn't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use RabbitMq RESTful API.

https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.10.5/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html

e.g. `/api/exchanges`